# Empty rows in SPSS for anova output

Tags: spss, anova

I am trying to run a 4 way mixed ANOVA however some rows come up empty for some reason and I don't know why. Below is a sample of one of the output tables[image]

```
GLM NormalizedJerk_102 NormalizedJerk_104 BY Test GROUP condition
  /WSFACTOR=factor1 2 Polynomial 
  /METHOD=SSTYPE(3)
  /POSTHOC=GROUP condition(BONFERRONI) 
  /EMMEANS=TABLES(OVERALL) 
  /EMMEANS=TABLES(factor1) COMPARE ADJ(BONFERRONI)
  /EMMEANS=TABLES(Test) COMPARE ADJ(BONFERRONI)
  /EMMEANS=TABLES(GROUP) COMPARE ADJ(BONFERRONI)
  /EMMEANS=TABLES(condition) COMPARE ADJ(BONFERRONI)
  /EMMEANS=TABLES(Test*GROUP) 
  /EMMEANS=TABLES(Test*condition) 
  /EMMEANS=TABLES(Test*factor1) compare(factor1)adj(BONFERRONI)
  /EMMEANS=TABLES(GROUP*condition) 
  /EMMEANS=TABLES(GROUP*factor1) compare(factor1)adj(BONFERRONI)
  /EMMEANS=TABLES(condition*factor1) compare(factor1)adj(BONFERRONI)
  /EMMEANS=TABLES(Test*GROUP*condition)
  /EMMEANS=TABLES(Test*GROUP*factor1) compare(factor1)adj(BONFERRONI)
  /EMMEANS=TABLES(Test*condition*factor1) compare(factor1)adj(BONFERRONI)
  /EMMEANS=TABLES(GROUP*condition*factor1) compare(factor1)adj(BONFERRONI)
  /EMMEANS=TABLES(Test*GROUP*condition*factor1)  compare(factor1)adj(BONFERRONI)
  /PRINT=ETASQ 
  /CRITERIA=ALPHA(.05)
  /WSDESIGN=factor1 
  /DESIGN=Test GROUP condition Test*GROUP Test*condition GROUP*condition Test*GROUP*condition.
```

Answer (score 1):

You've probably resolved this by now, and I can't be certain without seeing your data, but it looks like a colinearity issue. SPSS produces blank cells for independent variables which are perfectly predictable from another independent variable. Your output is what you'd expect to see if everyone who was assigned a score of 0 for factor1 was also assigned a score of 0 for Time, everyone who was assigned a score of 1 for factor1 was also assigned a score of 1 for Time, and so on.